# diminishing interest rate computation

Tags: java

I have this computations:

Amount of Loan:    P 3,000

No. of Payments:       3

Interest Rate"       .02

Computing for monthly payments plus diminishing interest.

3,000 divided by 3 equals 1,000 payment per amortization.

3,000 multiplied .02 equals 60 First Payment Interest.
2,000 multiplied .02 equals 40 Second Payment Interest.
1,000 multiplied .02 equals 20 Third Payment Interest.

Total Interest equals 60 plus 40 plus 20 equals 120.
Interest per month equals 120 divided by 3 equals 40.

Total Monthly Amortization:

Principal Loan Amortization equals  1,000

plus: Loan Interest    equals        40

Total Monthly Amortization equals   1,040

How do I achieved this using java, any suggestion

Comment: You can achieve this by writing some code!

Comment: Please understand that SO is not a site where you drop requirements and other people jump up to do **your** work. People here are willing to help with your programming problems; but they will not help you with such questions.

Comment: i have solve this by using this equation Laon x interestRate x (1 plus interesRate) raise to the power of numberOfPayment divided by (1 plus interestRate) raise to the power numberOfPayment less one multiplied by Loan. –  Miguel James 16 hours ago   
     
sorry if i did ask the question right away with out solving it my self.... –  Miguel James 16 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

I went over your problem description and re-wrote your English in Java:

```
public static double getMonthlyAmortization 
    (double loan, int payments, double interest) {

    paymentPerAmortization = loan / payments;
    double totalInterest = 0.0;
    double currLoan = loan;
    while (currLoan > 0) {
        totalInterest += (currLoan * interest);
        currLoan -= paymentPerAmortization;
    }
    interestPerPayment = totalInterest / payments;

    return paymentPerAmortization + interestPerPayment;
}
```

Comment: i have solve this by using this equation Laon x interestRate x (1 plus interesRate) raise to the power of numberOfPayment divided by (1 plus interestRate) raise to the power numberOfPayment less one multiplied by Loan.